# Call on a variable created in another loop in Java, and how to have multiple conditions in a do...while loop

Tags: java

I am creating a rock paper scissors game for class at school. I got everything to work, except for setting up something to restate the question when an invalid choice is answered. I figured a do...while statement was best here, but I realized that I am calling on a variable within the "do" part of the loop. So, since it's calling on something from another loop, it can't find that variable. Also, in my while statements, did I correctly list the variables that are acceptable? I'm pretty sure I just made that part up.

Thanks so much for your help guys!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RockPaperScissorsTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in );
        do {
            System.out.println("Player 1, choose 1 for rock, 2 for paper, or 3 for scissors.");
            int P1 = input.nextInt();
        } while (P != 1; P1 != 2; P1 != 3);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        do {
            System.out.println("Player 2, choose 1 for rock, 2 for paper, or 3 for scissors.");
            int P2 = input.nextInt();
        } while (P2 != 1; P2 != 2; P2 != 3);
        if (P1 == 1 & P2 == 1)
            System.out.println("It's a tie!");
        if (P1 == 1 & P2 == 2)
            System.out.println("Player 2 wins!");
        if (P1 == 1 & P2 == 3)
            System.out.println("Player 1 wins!");
        if (P1 == 2 & P2 == 1)
            System.out.println("Player 1 wins!");
        if (P1 == 2 & P2 == 2)
            System.out.println("It's a tie!");
        if (P1 == 2 & P2 == 3)
            System.out.println("Player 2 wins!");
        if (P1 == 3 & P2 == 1)
            System.out.println("Player 2 wins!");
        if (P1 == 3 & P2 == 2)
            System.out.println("Player 1 wins");
        if (P1 == 3 & P2 == 3)
            System.out.println("It's a tie!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Step 1: Format your code legibly. :-) *(I've done it for you on this occasion.)*

Comment: Step 2, if P1 == P2, you lose 3 unnecessary conditions

Comment: What do you mean by "if P1==P2." Should I redo my conditions in the while statement?

Comment: P1 == P2 is the same thing like: P1 == 1 && P2 == 1, P1 == 2 && P2 == 2, P1 == 3 && P2 == 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several things jump out:

1. In Java (and most other languages syntactically derived from B), the *logical* AND operator is `&&`, not `&` (`&` is a mathematical operator, doing a bitwise boolean OR).

   So

   ```
   if (P1 == 1 && P2 == 1)
   //          ^^---- &&, not &
   ```
2. In Java, variables have block scope. That means that a variable declared within a block is only available within that block (and any blocks it contains), not *outside* that block. So the `P2` you're defining inside the loop here:

   ```
   do {
       System.out.println("Player 2, choose 1 for rock, 2 for paper, or 3 for scissors.");
       int P2 = input.nextInt();
   //  ^----------------------------- here
   } while (/*...*/);
   ```

   ...will only be available *within* the loop, not later after the loop. You need to declare that variable outside the loop. (And similarly for `P1`, of course.) In this case, the best place is the top of the function:

   ```
   int P1, P2;
   ```
3. In any logical condition (including the condition of a `while`), to combine multiple criteria, you use logical operators `&&` ("and") and `||` ("or"), not semicolons (`;`). So for instance:

   ```
   do {
       System.out.println("Player 2, choose 1 for rock, 2 for paper, or 3 for scissors.");
       P2 = input.nextInt();
   } while (P2 != 1 && P2 != 2 && P2 != 3);
   //               ^^---------^^---- "If P2 is not 1 AND P2 is not 2 AND P2 is not 3"
   ```
4. You have three different tests to see if it's a tie, and just generally you're doing a lot of retesting of the same conditions (lots of `P1 == 1`, `P2 == 2`, etc.). You can test for a tie simply by checking if `P1 == P2`, and you can reduce the number of condition checks markedly by using `else`, for instance:

   ```
   if (P1 == P2) {
       System.out.println("It's a tie!");
   }
   else if (P1 == 1) {
       if (P2 == 2) {
           System.out.println("Player 2 wins!");
       }
       else {
           System.out.println("Player 1 wins!");
       }
   }
   else if (P1 == 2) {
       if (P2 == 1) {
           System.out.println("Player 1 wins!");
       }
       else {
           System.out.println("Player 2 wins!");
       }
   }
   else { // P1 == 3
       if (P2 == 1) {
           System.out.println("Player 2 wins!");
       }
       else {
           System.out.println("Player 1 wins");
       }
   }
   ```
5. *(More advanced)* Look into `enum`s. In my reworking your logic, I simply trusted that your logic was correct, because I have no idea what `1`, `2`, or `3` are when looking at the code. (Obviously higher up I could look at the message you output.) Using an `enum` would make the code a lot clearer. (`if (P2 == RPS.Paper)`)

I suggest working through some guided Java tutorials. Oracle [has several](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Comment: My bad. Thanks so much. So, how do I call on P1 and P2 in the while statement since it is in the do loop?

Comment: @ZeroConnor: What do you mean by "call on"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variables global. At the point where you declare the scanner. And only initialize it in the loop.

out of the loop:

```
int P1;
```

in the loop only do:

```
P1 = input.nextInt();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, between this and T.J Crowder's first answer, I fixed my problem. You guys are awesome! Thanks for helping me clean up my program too!

Answer (score 0):

As @TJ. Crowder told you, need to understand the ´AND´ (´&&´) operation and ´OR´ (´||´)

This is a compiling approach to your solution, but you need to improve the code to get it working. Hope you have a good time learning Java.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RockPaperScissorsTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in );
    int P1 = 0;
    int P2 = 0;
    do {
        System.out.println("Player 1, choose 1 for rock, 2 for paper, or 3 for scissors.");
        P1 = input.nextInt();
    } while (P1 != 1 && P1 != 2 && P1 != 3);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");
    do {
        System.out.println("Player 2, choose 1 for rock, 2 for paper, or 3 for scissors.");
        P2 = input.nextInt();
    } while (P2 != 1 && P2 != 2 && P2 != 3);
    if (P1 == 1 && P2 == 1)
        System.out.println("It's a tie!");
    if (P1 == 1 && P2 == 2)
        System.out.println("Player 2 wins!");
    if (P1 == 1 && P2 == 3)
        System.out.println("Player 1 wins!");
    if (P1 == 2 && P2 == 1)
        System.out.println("Player 1 wins!");
    if (P1 == 2 && P2 == 2)
        System.out.println("It's a tie!");
    if (P1 == 2 && P2 == 3)
        System.out.println("Player 2 wins!");
    if (P1 == 3 && P2 == 1)
        System.out.println("Player 2 wins!");
    if (P1 == 3 && P2 == 2)
        System.out.println("Player 1 wins");
    if (P1 == 3 && P2 == 3)
        System.out.println("It's a tie!");
}
```

}